# The easiest way to change z-index in the builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I am building the presentation builder where I am appending different elements (text, pictures, decorative elements). I am using jquery UI to resize and drag, but the problem is I don't know how I can manipulate the z-index.

I would like to add functionality to sort the order of overlying.

The elements are added dynamically and there is no limit for the number of them.

So f.e. if I add class with z-index: 1 for all my elements it will not help. 
I need them to be swappable: if I have 4 elements, I have 4 classes: .el1 {z-index= 1}, .el2 {z-index= 2}, .el3 {z-index= 3}, .el4 {z-index= 4}, and if i want to get .el1 on the surface I have to give it a z-index:5;

How to do it in a most efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean with manipulating the `z-index`? When should that happen? `jQuery('element').css('z-index','your z index')`?

Answer (score 1):

In **jQuery**, you can use [**`.css()`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to dynamically change the `z-index` property.

like

```
$(element).css('z-index', '1');
```

In-case JS,

```
  var element = document.getElementById(id).style;  
  element.zIndex = 1;
```

Comment: but if I add class with z-index: 1 for all my elements it will not help me. I need them to be swappable: if I have 4 elements, I have 4 classes: z-index= 1,  z-index= 2,  z-index= 3,  z-index= 4, and if i want to get element 1 on the surface I have to give it a z-index:5;